# Wordpress preg_replace '&nbsp;' tags in post_content with insert_post_data not working

Tags: php, wordpress, preg-replace

I have `&nbsp;` tags as spaces in autocreated posts in Wordpress and trying to replace them before posting/saving. Text sample below:

```
This&nbsp;is&nbsp;an&nbsp;Example&nbsp;of&nbsp;how&nbsp;my&nbsp;text&nbsp;looks
```

Believe this code placed in "functions.php" should replace the tags with spaces

```
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data' , 'nbsp_remover' , '99', 2 );

function nbsp_remover($data) {
    $pattern = '/\&nbsp\;/';
    $data['post_content'] = preg_replace($pattern, ' ', $data['post_content']);
    return $data;
}
```

But this doesn't work.

- I tested the regex and it works.
- when I change the pattern to a word in the text it works

But not with the `&nbsp;` tags in the html...

Any idea?

EDIT 1

when dumping $data as suggested using `var_dump($data['post_content']); die;`

creating a new post manually, opens blank window with:

> array(21) { ["post_author"]=> int(1) ["post_date"]=> string(19)
> "2021-01-26 17:15:29" ["post_date_gmt"]=> string(19) "0000-00-00
> 00:00:00" ["post_content"]=> string(0) "" ["post_content_filtered"]=>
> string(0) "" ["post_title"]=> string(10) "Auto Draft"
> ["post_excerpt"]=> string(0) "" ["post_status"]=> string(10)
> "auto-draft" ["post_type"]=> string(4) "post" ["comment_status"]=>
> string(4) "open" ["ping_status"]=> string(4) "open"
> ["post_password"]=> string(0) "" ["post_name"]=> string(0) ""
> ["to_ping"]=> string(0) "" ["pinged"]=> string(0) ""
> ["post_modified"]=> string(19) "2021-01-26 17:15:29"
> ["post_modified_gmt"]=> string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
> ["post_parent"]=> int(0) ["menu_order"]=> int(0) ["post_mime_type"]=>
> string(0) "" ["guid"]=> string(0) "" }

EDIT 2
This with `\xA0`or ' ' did not work

```
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data' , 'nbsp_remover' , '99', 2 );

function nbsp_remover($data) {
    return str_replace('\xA0', '', $data); 
}
```

Comment: The text sample is the what you have in `$data`? Can you add the output of `var_dump($data['post_content']);` before your `preg_replace`?

Comment: I forgot to add I'm an beginner at WP and this is first time ever trying a php script so not sure what you are suggesting @ChinLeung

Comment: Add `var_dump($data['post_content']); die;` as the first line in your `nbsp_remover` function, and try to create a new post. It will display the content of `$data['post_content']`, and copy paste it into your question. :)

Comment: I added the line - Now when I try to add new post manually i get a white screen stating:   -  string(0) ""  -

Comment: It is highly probably all your `&nbsp;` are already turned into `\xA0`, try `return str_replace('\xA0', '', $data);`. BTW, you are not using the `$postarr` variable in the function.

Comment: noobing again, where should i place " return str_replace('\xA0', '', $data); " When inspecting the element in chrome on the WP page the &nbsp; tags are visible

Comment: `function nbsp_remover($data) {return str_replace('\xA0', '', $data); }`

Comment: `function nbsp_remover($data) {return str_replace('&nbsp;', '', $data); }` - Why regex?

Comment: Wait but the `$data['post_content']` is empty. Can you dump the `$data` instead?

Comment: @ChinLeung - so instead of  " var_dump($data['post_content']); die; "  i know have " var_dump($data); die; "    - When adding new post  manually i get a lot of " array(21){ information}

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for helping, I'm really novice, first time php so no idea how to implement your suggestion

Comment: Can you add the information you are getting and update your question with the output? I need to see the content of the array.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew tried both your suggestions as mentioned in the updated original post, but no results

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved my issue by circumventing it...

As noted above I couldn't find a way to remove the `&nbsp;` tags from the post content.

I was able to edit the posts before they got send and read by wordpress. So I replaced all spaces with a special character before the post got created in WP and than used the regex code to replace that character with spaces.